# Does Java 8 provide a good way to repeat a function based on specific condition?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java-8

I am having the old style `while` loop like below:

```
int i = 1, n = 5;
while(i <= n) {
    if (doSomething()) { 
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Is it possible to do it in a good way in Java 8?

Comment: What's "not good" with a while loop? It works, it's efficient, it's understandable, …?

Comment: In your example, doSomething doesn't depend on i, so it either returns true or false at every iteration. You should be more specific about the actual context...

Comment: Do you need to know what value `i` had when the repetition ended?

Comment: `for(int i = 1, n = 5; i <= n && !doSomething(); i++) { … }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and [findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#findFirst--) short-circuiting terminal operation. And when ever `doSomething()` method returns true the execution of stream pipeline will be terminated

```
IntStream.range(1,5)
         .filter(i -> doSomething())
         .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 3):

Even though you have mentioned Java 8, if you are going to use Java 9 or above and need to know the number of times the loop was executed, then do as follows:

```java
long count = IntStream.range(1,6)
                      .takeWhile(i -> !doSomething()) // loop continued till doSomething is true
                      .count();
```

`takeWhile` was introduced in Java 9.

Answer (score 2):

Plain old approach:

```java
while(i <= n && !doSomething()) { 
    // do something here
    i++;
}
```

Pretty clear and concise.

Answer (score 1):

This is tidier:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5 && !doSomething(); i++);
```

Comment: But `i` won't be in scope when the loop is finished.